# How do I call a function from a file in an activity with no class Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to be able to have neater code and have a Utility file for all sorts of functions and things. I want to know how to call functions IN an activity FROM a .Kt file not a class.

I haven't been successful in this direction. Any examples I've found were very complex and/or unsuccessful. Additionally, when I throw some functions into a file or even a Class folder I get errors because it looses references that the activities gives automatically, such as referencing "this".

Example, how do I call one of the following in main.Kt?

**Utilities.Kt** File:

```
package ...

imports ...    

    // Hide keyboard utilities
private fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    hideKeyboard(currentFocus ?: View(this))
}

@SuppressLint("ServiceCast")
fun Context.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
    val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as 
    InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}

    // Alert dialogue for null/empty field
private fun nullEmptyAlert() {
    val box = AlertDialog.Builder(ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom))

    with(box) {
        box.setTitle("Empty Field!")
        box.setMessage("Calculator cannot compute values with empty field. Please enter unit dimension in mm.")
        box.setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ -> }
        box.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you do it in application class

Comment: Thats an option I will research further, thanks for input

Answer (score 2):

You can create a singleton class `ConstantFunction`

```
object ConstantFunction {

    fun hideKeyboard(activity : Activity){
    hideKeyboard(currentFocus ?: View(activity)) }                                          
}
```

and call it in your `main.kt` like this

```
ConstantFunction.hideKeyboard(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two of your functions: `Context.hideKeyboard()` and `Activity.hideKeyboard()` are [extension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) functions. You call them with with instance of class that you extended. In your activities you can easily call both of them with `this` keyword:

```
this.hideKeyword()
this.hideKeyword(someView)
```

And the other function, you can easily call them after importing that **Utilities.kt** file in your desired file.

Comment: I got the hideKeyboard functions to work like mentioned. I'm still having trouble importing files into activities for some reason. I did: `import ...Utilities.Kt` but no go no connect... I must be doing something wrong??

Comment: then, just try to call `nullEmptyAlert()` function, IDE wil help you

Comment: True! I'm having trouble creating this function in the file: `// Alert dialogue for null/empty field
private fun nullEmptyAlert () {
    val box = AlertDialog.Builder(ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom))

    with(box) {
        box.setTitle("Empty Field(s)!")
        box.setMessage("Calculator cannot compute values with empty field(s). Please fill all fields with dimensions in mm.")
        box.setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ -> }
        box.show()
    }
}`   The "this" is causing an error and I don't know how to create the function in a file in this manner...

Comment: This should be regarded as separate question. But I will answer. `AlertDialog.Builder` demands `Context` in its constructor. So it is better to write that function as extension function of `Context`.

Comment: Tuqay, I've got it sorted out now. I ended up putting all my utilities into an object file. Then I could call the alert functions by instantiating the object and, weirdly enough could call the hideKeyboard directly... code is much neater now. Thanks for all the input, I've learned a lot from this post!!